# convert to datetime not working sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, db2

i have this:

```
let startDateRange = loadYear + '-' + loadMonth + '-01'
let endDateRange = loadYear + '-' + loadMonth + '-31'
var getschedule = "select * from SCHEDULE where DATE BETWEEN '" + CONVERT(DATETIME, startDateRange) + "' AND '" + CONVERT(DATETIME, endDateRange) + "'"
```

and in `startDateRange` and `endDateRange`, it is formatted in a string like so:

```
'2021-Dec-01'
```

It is giving the error:

```
ReferenceError: CONVERT is not defined
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect `CONVERT` to exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cast to date time on sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320204/cast-to-date-time-on-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some fundamentals here, I think.

```
var getschedule = "select * from SCHEDULE where DATE BETWEEN '" + CONVERT(DATETIME, startDateRange) + "' AND '" + CONVERT(DATETIME, endDateRange) + "'"`
```

Javascript thinks `CONVERT` is a function that you've defined in your Javascript code rather than a SQL command. Though you didn't provide a ton of context, what you're probably trying to do is construct a complete SQL query. If you want to interpolate the values you've calculated in your Javascript to this query you're going to give to your SQL database, you need to construct a complete string.

It might be easier (or more readable) to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const getschedule = `select * from SCHEDULE where DATE BETWEEN 'CONVERT(DATETIME, ${startDateRange})' AND 'CONVERT(DATETIME, ${endDateRange})'`
```

Or you can concatenate strings as you tried the first time:

```
const getschedule = "select * from SCHEDULE where DATE BETWEEN 'CONVERT(DATETIME, " + startDateRange + ")' AND 'CONVERT(DATETIME, " + endDateRange + ")'";
```

Full disclosure: I have no idea whether or not this SQL query will be valid for you, it's just clear that you're thinking the wrong way about Javascript functions and how to construct strings.